# What is the difference between Memory Profiling and Memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, ipad

What is the difference between Memory Profiling and Memory leak fixing in Objective C or in any Programming language?
Any  help appreciated in advance, Thank You.

Comment: memory profiling is a tool to find the problem, memory leak is the problem, memory leak fixing are the changes needed to get rid off the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Memory Profiling** is the process of determining how memory is being used by your application.  This could include searching for memory leaks, but would also encompass determining how much memory non leaked objects are using.

**Memory leak fixing**, is specifically tracking down and fixing memory leaks.  These are where you have objects on the heap with no references pointing at them.  They can't be used for anything, and are therefore reducing the amount of overall memory your application has available to it.

Answer (score 3):

Memory Profiler - The tool or the software to measure memory usage, memory leaks, etc. Instruments is the memory profiler for Xcode.

Memory Leak Fixing in objective C is that, Objective C doesnt have garbage collection. So, you urself are responsible for allocation and de-allocation of the objects you use. Hence, sometimes when anyone forgets to de-allocate the memory allocated to some object, a memory leak occurs, which needs to be fixed!

Comment: Actually, Objective-C can be compiled with garbage collection. It seems not to be used very often, but it is possible.

Comment: well, i was talking about iphone and ipad programming. Garbage collection is available when you program for mac.